# Why am I getting nulls registered in my dto?

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, spring-mvc, dto

This is a small spring-boot project.

I have to print out :

```
[

   {

      "id":3,

      "name":”Item1”,

      "ownerId":1,

      “ownerUsername”:"User1"

   }

]
```

instead I get:

```
[{"id":null,"itemName":null,"ownerName":"ivan","ownerId":1}]
```

**Here is my User entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "account_num")
    private int account;

    @Column(name = "is_seller")
    private boolean isSeller;

    public User() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public int getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    public void setAccount(int account) {
        this.account = account;
    }

    public boolean isSeller() {
        return isSeller;
    }

    public void setSeller(boolean seller) {
        isSeller = seller;
    }
}
```

**Here is my Item entity:**

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "item_name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    public Item() {
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User userId) {
        this.user = userId;
    }
}
```

**Here is my ItemService:**

```
@Service
public class ItemServiceImp  {

    @Autowired
    private ItemRepository itemRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;


    public List<ItemsOwnedByUserDto> getAllItems() {
        return userRepository.findAll()
                .stream()
                .map(this::itemsOwnedByUserDto)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }


    public ItemsOwnedByUserDto itemsOwnedByUserDto(User user) {
        ItemsOwnedByUserDto dto =
                modelMapper.map(Item.class, ItemsOwnedByUserDto.class);
        Item item = new Item();

        dto.setId(item.getId());
        dto.setItemName(item.getName());
        dto.setOwnerId(user.getId());
        dto.setOwnerName(user.getUserName());
        return dto;
    }
}
```

**Here is my Controller calss:**

```
@RestController
public class ItemViewController {

    @Autowired
    private ItemServiceImp itemServiceImp;


    @GetMapping("/users-items")
    public List<ItemsOwnedByUserDto> viewItems(){
        return itemServiceImp.getAllItems();
    }
}
```

[I have created rows in the database, but it seems like I can't retrieve them inside the Service.This is the **items** table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyGf0.png)

[And this is the **users** table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef6ju.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a brand new `Item` object before setting properties in your DTO. That is why you are getting `id` and `itemName` as null.

```java
public ItemsOwnedByUserDto itemsOwnedByUserDto(User user) {
    ItemsOwnedByUserDto dto =
            modelMapper.map(Item.class, ItemsOwnedByUserDto.class);
    Item item = new Item();

    dto.setId(item.getId());          // item.getId() is null
    dto.setItemName(item.getName());  // item.getName() is null
    dto.setOwnerId(user.getId());
    dto.setOwnerName(user.getUserName());
    return dto;
}
```